# "Debugging" bash shell script: escaping characters, passing arguments

Tags: bash, debugging, shell, command-line

I am trying to write a bash shell script (which is something I don't have much experience with) to search in C code on the Unix machine I'm operating through ssh.

This is the code in my script:

```
#! /bin/bash

find . \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' \) -exec grep -n '<SEARCH_STRING>' {} + | sed -e "s/^\(\..*\.c\):\([0-9]*\):[ \t]*\(.*\)$/\1 :: \2\n\3\n/" | sed -e "s/^\(\..*\.h\):\([0-9]*\):[ \t]*\(.*\)$/\1 :: \2\n\3\n/" | sed ''/<SEARCH_STRING>/s//`printf "\033[31m<SEARCH_STRING>\033[0m"`/'' | less -R
```

Note that  is merely what I use to represent my search string, of course I'm not actually searching for this literally.

I realise there are a couple of things wrong with this. First of all, when I type the bottom line (the "script" without its #!/bin/bash header) into the command line, it actually works just fine and gives me the result I want. I know that I should escape certain characters when making it into a bash script, but I've tried escaping several (combinations of) characters and it always gives me the same error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
./code_search.sh: line 4: <SEARCH_STRING>: command not found
sed: -e expression #1, char 43: unterminated `s' command
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
./code_search.sh: line 8: \033[31m<SEARCH_STRING>\033[0m: command not found
sed: -e expression #1, char 46: unterminated `s' command
```

Also, I realise I shouldn't hard-code the search string into my script, as it's a lot more convenient to give the search string to the script as a parameter, but I really can't figure out how to do that either.

As I said, I don't have a lot of experience writing bash scripts, and I tried writing this script to help me with my coding work. However, I can't spend any more time on debugging this seeing as that's not what my boss pays me to do. I've asked my colleagues, but none of them can help me either.

I know it's a little cheap not to put in a lot of effort to learn more about bash shell scripting myself, but like I said I really can't spare the time. Could anyone please help me finish this script?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In this way it doesn't give any error.

```
#! /bin/bash

searchstring=$1

find . \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' \) -exec grep -n "$searchstring" {} + \ 
        | sed -e "s/^\(\..*\.c\):\([0-9]*\):[ \t]*\(.*\)$/\1 :: \2\n\3\n/" \
        | sed -e "s/^\(\..*\.h\):\([0-9]*\):[ \t]*\(.*\)$/\1 :: \2\n\3\n/" \
        | sed ''/"$searchstring"/s//`printf "\033[31m""$searchstring""\033[0m"`/'' \
        | less -R
```

However, that doesn't mean it works. Without some sample input and the desired output, it's impossible to help you further. For example the third `sed` seems to be wrong to me.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

sample input is something like `./code_search.sh isValid`, sample output is something like

`/users/user/code/codefile1.c :: 15
boolean isValid, activatesCheck;

/users/user/code/codefile1.c :: 321
if(!isValid) {`

I still get an error when running it though; appearantly there's a problem with find:

`find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]`

Answer (score 0):

This is because, in the last sed command, the character < is not escaped : double single quote just means empty string ''; and the < is interpreted as file redirection, shell tries to read from the file "SEARCH_STRING".

```
sed ''/<SEARCH_STRING>/s//`printf "\033[31m<SEARCH_STRING>\033[0m"`/''
```

should be changed to

```
sed '/<SEARCH_STRING>/s//'`printf "\033[31m<SEARCH_STRING>\033[0m"`'/'
```

Also, following the errors, the find version may not support the + at the end of command look at `man find`, in this case + functionnality can be done by xargs (but this can fail if file names can contain spaces)

```
find . \( ... \) | xargs grep -n '<SEARCH_STRING>'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

I've tried changing what you suggested (both combined and separately), but I still can't get the script to work.

I still get an error whenever I change something; appearantly there's a problem with find:

`find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]`